# Error when instantiate chaincode

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric

Please help me this issue, error happened when I instantiate my chaincode:

Currently, I guess the issue related to shim package, because I remove it in my utils package, instantiate successfully.

## MyChainCode:

```
import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/hex"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strconv"

    "github.com/golang/protobuf/proto"
    "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim"
    "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/msp"
    pb "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer"
    "github.com/myproj/models"
    "github.com/myproj/packages/utils"
)

APIstub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface
...
username, _ = utils.GetCurrentUser(APIstub)
...
```

## My packages

```
package utils

import (
    "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt"
)

func GetCurrentUser(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) (string, error) {
    cert, err := GetCreatorCert(stub)

    return cert.Subject.CommonName, err
}
```

## Issue:

> Error: Error endorsing chaincode: rpc error: code = Unknown desc =
>   error starting container: Failed to generate platform-specific docker
>   build: Error returned from build: 2 "#
>   ~vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/docker/docker/pkg/archive
>   ~vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/docker/docker/pkg/archive/archive.go:364:5:
>   hdr.Format undefined (type *tar.Header has no field or method Format)
>   ~vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/docker/docker/pkg/archive/archive.go:364:15:
>   undefined: tar.FormatPAX
>   ~/vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/docker/docker/pkg/archive/archive.go:1166:7:
>   hdr.Format undefined (type *tar.Header has no field or method Format)
>   ~/vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/docker/docker/pkg/archive/archive.go:1166:17:
>   undefined: tar.FormatPAX

Fabric ver 1.1.0

Go ver 1.9.2

Comment: For anyone got this issue, switch to release 1.1 branch in hyperledger fabric github, it will solve the problem. In master branch, pkg/archive/archive.go seems like for old version, release 1.1 they upgraded pkg/archive/archive.go. It will work for fabric 1.1

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem after upgrading fabric to 1.2.0. Fabric 1.2.0 requires go 1.10.x. So I upgraded go lang to 1.10.3 and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

That can be because you have old version in some files inside your hyperledger/fabric folder.

If you are following the chaincode tutorial, you can just remove your hyperledger/fabric folder.

Regards

Comment: I solved the issue, just check out release 1.1 not master. Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue by following the documentation.
Switching to branch 'release-1.1' solves the issue.

After cloning the repository proceed with:

```
hyperleger$ cd fabric
hyperledger/fabric$ git fetch
hyperledger/fabric$ git checkout release-1.1
```