# Hyperledger Fabric 1.2.0 developer chaincode tutorial failed to go get and build

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Attempting to follow the [hyperledger fabric 1.2.0 developers chaincode tutorial](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/chaincode4ade.html).

I was unable to get the hyperledger fabric dependencies by executing
`go get -u github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim`. I tried deleting the `hyperledger/fabric` source folder from my GOPATH's `src` directory as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50939512/error-when-instantiate-chaincode), but the same error messages keep popping up:

```
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/docker/docker/pkg/archive
../github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/docker/docker/pkg/archive/archive.go:364:5: hdr.Format undefined (type *tar.Header has no field or method Format)
../github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/docker/docker/pkg/archive/archive.go:364:15: undefined: tar.FormatPAX
../github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/docker/docker/pkg/archive/archive.go:1166:7: hdr.Format undefined (type *tar.Header has no field or method Format)
../github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/docker/docker/pkg/archive/archive.go:1166:17: undefined: tar.FormatPAX
```

Skipping the `go get` command and going straight to `go build` would output the same error as above.

I've also tried [installing gnu-tar](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/dev-setup/devenv.html) to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reinstalling the latest stable version of Golang did the trick. At the time of this writing the [stable version of go](https://golang.org/dl/) is 1.10.3.

The issue was caused by golang version 1.9.3 having an undefined struct for `tar.FormatPAX` which was needed for one of the hyperledger fabric go source files.